# J: Coordinates with specific value

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, j

Let's say we have array

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 8 7 8 9
```

There are two indexes that have value 8:

```
(i.10) ([#~8={) 0 1 2 3 4 5 8 7 8 9
6 8
```

Is there any shorter way to get this result? May be some built-in verb.

But more important. What about higher dimensions?
Let's say we have matrix 5x4

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
```

I want to find out what are coordinates with value 6.
I want to get result such (there are three coordinates):

```
4 1
3 2
2 3
```

It's pretty basic task and I think it should exist some simple solution.

The same in three dimensions?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verb [indices `I.`](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dicapdot.htm) almost does the job.

When you have a simple list, `I.`'s use is straightforward:

```
I. 8 = 0 1 2 3 4 5 8 7 8 9
6 8
```

For higher order matrices you can pair it with [antibase `#:`](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d402.htm) to get the coordinates in base `$ matrix`. Eg:

```
]a =: 4 5 $ 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8

I. 6 = ,a
9 13 17

($a) #: 9 13 17
1 4
2 3
3 2
```

Similarly, for any number of dimensions: flatten (`,`), compare (`=`), get indices (`I.`) and convert coordinates (`($a)&#:`):

```
]coords =: ($a) #: I. 5 = , a =: ? 5 6 7 $ 10
0 0 2
0 2 1
0 2 3
...
(<"1 coords) { a
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

By the way, you can write `I. x = y` as `x (I.@:=) y` for extra performance. It is [special code](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/release/edot504.htm) for

> indices where x f y

Answer (score 5):

Using [Sparse](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d211.htm) array functionality (`$.`) provides a very fast and lean solution that also works for multiple dimensions.

```
   ]a=: 5 ]\ 1 + i. 8
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
   6 = a
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0
   4 $. $. 6 = a
1 4
2 3
3 2
```

Tacitly:

```
   getCoords=: 4 $. $.
   getCoords 6 = a ,: a
0 1 4
0 2 3
0 3 2
1 1 4
1 2 3
1 3 2
```

Comment: Never noticed that before. Very interesting. On a `1e5 x 1e5` integer matrix, `$.` is  about 3 times faster and uses 1/10 space.